# RaisePropertyChanged doesn't update binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm

I've come across some strange behavior.  I have a control that binds to a property like so:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="ProjectBeheerLink"
       Visibility="{Binding IsBeheerder, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

In my viewmodel I have the property implemented like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property IsBeheerder As Boolean
    Get
        Return iwtApp.AllMyFunctieRollen.Any(Function(x) x.Rol.Equals(Constants.RoleBeheerder))
    End Get
End Property
```

Then when I raise my PropertyChanged event in my callback method

```
Private Sub GetMyPersonCompleted(ByVal lo As LoadOperation(Of FunctieRol))
    'Init FunctieRollen ect. ...
    RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.IsBeheerder)
End Sub
```

**my binding does not update.**

**However**! If I implement a backend field like this:

```
        _isBeheerder = iwtApp.AllMyFunctieRollen.Any(Function(x) x.Rol.Equals(Constants.RoleBeheerder))
        RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.IsBeheerder)
```

And change my property like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property IsBeheerder As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isBeheerder
    End Get
End Property
```

Everything works fine... Can someone explain me this behavior?

Just curious as to why..

Comment: I don't quite understand where you raise the property changed event in the non working version...

Comment: What's the point of programming in dutch? :)

Comment: @Daniel: I raise the property changed in my callback from the service. I'll edit my question to provide more clarity.

@ Steven: It's a b*tch translating all the entities otherwise :P

Comment: Did you check that RaisePropertyChanged is really called and that it raises the event with the property name set to "IsBeheerder"? I don't understand the VB syntax of your parameter to RaisePropertyChanged

Comment: @Daniel: The RaisePropertyChanged event is actually called and raised with the correct propertyname.  I normally program in C# to, but atm I'm at a customer that wants VB.NET.  The strange thing is that it works if use a backend field that holds the value, for the rest there isn't much change in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to implement a bound property is as follows:

```
    Dim _isBeheerder As Boolean
    Public ReadOnly Property IsBeheerder As Boolean
        Get
            Return _isBeheerder
        End Get
        Set
            If value <> _isBeheerder Then
                _isBeheerder = value
                RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.IsBeheerder)
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
```

then in your service callback you just set this property:

```
    Private Sub GetMyPersonCompleted(ByVal lo As LoadOperation(Of FunctieRol))
        IsBeheerder = myNewValue
    End Sub
```

Comment: Problem is that when I have recieved my entities from the service I need to invoke a RaisePropertyChanged.

Also isn't the RaisePropertyChanged unreachable?  Since you return from the getter before you can call the RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: The RaisePropertyChanged is unreachable and doesn't make any sense anyway. It should be called in the Setter not the Getter, because the getter is called in response to the event, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes you are both right - sorry, misread the original code (it was in dutch after all!) - updated my answer.

Comment: I understand your answer, and it is correct but I wanted to avoid writing a setter for my property since it is another object that exposes the property.  The needed collection is loaded in an object iwtApp.  I was just wondering whether or not there is some kind of bug in the binding that does not detect a change in my property when i expose it as a LINQ query.